# JBOSS EAP 6 JMX MBeans via rmi

Tags: jboss7.x, jmx, mbeans, jboss-eap-6

I am kind of new to JMX , Here I am trying to use jconsole provided by jdk to remotely read the MBeans of JBOSS EAP 6. I followed tutorial ,http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-remote-connect-jconsole-to-jboss.html with this I am able to read remotely with the jconsole provided by eap 6 (EAP6_HOME)/bin/jconsole.sh ,but I was not able to do the same with jconsole of jdk ? Please give your thought on this.  I suspect it may be due to the remoting-jmx protocol of the (service:jmx:remoting-jmx://192.168.0.3:9999 ) jmx remote url. Does jboss-eap6 support rmi(service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://ipadress/mbeanname) protocol to read MBeans in jconsole?

Thanks,
Leo.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there will be a MBeans tab in the window of jconsole when connected as :

```
              service:jmx:remoting-jmx://jbossHost:9999
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use remoting-jmx protocol you need to have `jboss-client.jar` or `jboss-cli-client.jar` on the JConsole classpath.

Here is the relevant part from jconsole.sh provided by JBoss:

```
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar"

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="$CLASSPATH" "$@"
```

P.S. You might need to create some user account first. See `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh`